# How to stack fontawesome icons

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am trying to implement similar to the one in the attachment.

[image]

Below is my code. i get the envelope icon but dont know how to get the expected result by placing another icon.

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.wrap{

  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.wrap > .fa-commenting-o{
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'/>


<div class="wrap">
  <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<i class="fa fa-commenting-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Do you want like this?

Comment: Hi, thanks. want the comment icon to place on top of the envelope on the top corner as shown in my expected result.is it possible?thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
.text-danger {
    color: #d9534f;
}
```

```html
   

 <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'/>
<div class="container">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" aria-hidden="true">
      <i class="fa fa-camera fa-stack-1x"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-ban fa-stack-2x text-danger"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place your `<i></i>`s in a span like: Check [Fontawesome examples](http://fontawesome.io/examples/)

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-stack-2x"></i><!--Make background icon large-->
  <i class="fa fa-commenting-o fa-stack-1x"></i><!--make foreground icon smaller-->
</span>
```

Let me know how it works for you.
Have fun

Answer (score 1):

You can overlap icons using **CSS** property. Try this

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-commenting fa-stack-2x" style="padding-left:22px;margin-top:-16px;z-index:232"></i>
</span>
```

check it on fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sx7fk582/139/)